# Can I Add Session Cookies via DevTool?

Tags: firefox, cookies, devtools

When adding a new cookie, the expiration of the cookie would default to one day:
[image: Before]

Changing the expires field to "Session" or empty would results in "Invalid Date":
[image: After]

Of course it is possible to create session cookies by running something like `document.cookie = "foo=bar";`, just wondering if this is intended.